# error mapping array to string with Object.keys (javascript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object of type c.errors that returns, in a specific case:

> { required: true}

And I want to map this against the more general (and fixed array)

```
   validationMessages = {
    required: 'Please enter',
    pattern: 'Please enter valid'
  }
```

I also have an errorMessage property initialised with an empty string
  .
  My attempt was:

```
 this.errorMessage = Object.keys((c.errors).map(key => this.validationMessages[key]).join(' '));
```

Errors I get:

> Parameter 'key' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ required:
>   string; pattern: string; }' has no index signature.

Any advice?

this.errorMessage should contain 'Please enter' (that's my expectation after mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you index into a type that does not have an indexer, typescript expects the string you index by to be a key of the type. This means that in you case, `key` should be either string literal type `'required'` or `'pattern'`. Since `Object.keys` returns an array of `strings`, if you are certain that array will only contain valid keys for `validationMessages` you can just use a type assertion. Also you have some mismatched parenthesis:

```
this.errorMessage = Object.keys(c.errors).map((key) => this.validationMessages[key as 'required']).join(' ');
```

Comment: Thank you very much Titian. However I was hoping the mapping would be smarter in order to recognise which key matches. In this case it was the 'required' but in other cases it could be the 'pattern'

Comment: Would you advise looping through the existing array of keys to see which fits or is there a better version?

Comment: @annepic Unfortunately all methods of iterating through the keys of an object produce a string. (ie. `Object.keys`, `for(let key in o)`, `Object.entries`) I don't know of a way to do this without a type assertion. Best you cam do is create your own type safe `keys` function

Comment: @annepic Something like `function typedKeys<T>(o: T) : Array<keyof T> {
    return Object.keys(o) as  Array<keyof T>
} this.errorMessage = typedKeys(c.errors).map((key) => this.validationMessages[key]).join(' ');` But even this woul dbreak if errors was typed to have more then just `required` and you would still end up with a type assertion.